# Why is element.style.left returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-7

I'm getting a weird error where in Internet Explorer 7, when I call Math.round on a float it gives me an "Invalid Argument" error. Consider the following:

```
var elementLeft = parseInt(element.style.left); // Here we're actually getting NaN
function Foo(x) {
  this.x = x;

  this.apply = function(element) {
    element.style.left = Math.round(this.x) + 'px';
  };
}
Foo(elementLeft);
```

In this case `x` is a non-negative number and `element` is just a DOM element in my page (a div, in fact).

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The variable passed in as the `x` parameter is actually initialized earlier as `parseInt(element.style.left)`. It appears that the first time I try to read `element.style.left`, IE is actually giving back NaN. I have updated the code to reflect this. Anyone know any workarounds for this?

Comment: Have you tried to put alert(this.x) in your anonymous function? ;)

Comment: If it's really a float, that should work. Show also how you use the object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It appears that the first time I try to read element.style.left, IE is actually giving back NaN.

The first time you read `element.style.left`, is there actually any `left` style set on the element? Remember `element.style` only reflects style properties set in the inline `style="..."` attribute and not those applied by stylesheets.

If you haven't set an inline style, `style.left` will give you the `undefined` object, which does indeed `parseInt` to NaN.

Comment: We have a winner! I'm curious, what would get the left applied by a stylesheet?

Comment: `element.currentStyle` in IE; `document.getComputedStyle` in standards browsers. Parsing styles is generally bad news though, you don't always know what unit you're going to get and it's not trivial to convert. For measuring positioning specifically in pixels, the offsetLeft/Top/Width/Height/Parent properties tend to be easier to work with.

Answer (score 2):

### Is IE defaulting x to a bad value?

Scroll down to Item 10 on [this page](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/jquery-image-upload-crop):

> Everything was working fine in
>   Firefox, Google Chrome etal. But I was
>   having problems with IE (of all
>   flavours). No selection tool would be
>   presented and a javascript warning was
>   produced which told me about an
>   'Invalid argument' being submitted to
>   the Math.round function.
>
> The cause was that when you first
>   click on the image to start your
>   selection, the scaleX and scaleY
>   variables in the javascript on the
>   page result in a value of Infinity.
>   Firefox and every other browser seems
>   to silently step over this and carry
>   on processing as normal. IE of course
>   did not.
>
> The solution was to add the following
>   line after the initial scaleX and
>   scaleY variables are calculated. This
>   appears to have solved the problem
>   fully. if(scaleX == Infinity || scaleY
>   == Infinity) return false; I hope this helps someone else and saves them the
>   hour of hunting it cost me ;o)

Comment: I think you're right. x is actually passed a value that was loaded previously with an element.style.left. It appears that the first time I try to read element.style.left IE gives back NaN.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's `Math.round()` that's giving you the error. It's probably the CSS subsystem. Try an `alert()` on the value that you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Some frameworks such as jQuery have facilities to read the *calculated* position of elements -- without requiring you to have explicitly set CSS position properties on them. Try reading the position of your element through jQuery. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons Javascript only works for the inline styling.
For example

```
<div style="left:500px;"></div>
```

if you wish to work on the position of an element, try setting the initial position in Java Script file, example:

```
function Xyz() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('id');
    elem.style.left = 500px;
    numberLeft = 500;
    //Now you can manipulate the position
    var increment= 50;
    var newLeft = numberLeft + increment;
    elem.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
}
```

You get the idea. Put your logic in.