# Improving the performance of a pure Javascript smooth scroll with multiple list elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, scroll

I'm playing with replicating [the recent, 30-year Apple Mac retrospective](https://www.apple.com/30-years/) in pure CSS and Javascript for a small timeline of projects.  I have the basic layout of the first full screen hero and the scalloped, expand-on-hover working appropriately.  But the smooth scrolling of the timeline in the second half of the screen isn't working, even very slow scrolling is [obviously jittery](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4gC9Vrj1fI) in Google Chrome 32.0.1700.102 on Mac OS X.  You can download a folder with a single `index.html` and the necessary CSS and JS [here](http://cl.ly/3U0T2d1U2o3V).

Specifically, my two questions are:

1. What is a pure CSS/JavaScript solution to fixing this smooth scrolling?  I'd appreciate something which debugged this example rather than pointed me to another, working one.
2. And related, what could/should I do to approach debugging this to isolate the problem?  I naïvely tried collecting a JavaScript CPU Profile, but nothing jumped out as needing attention.

---

#### Basic Structure

The timeline is structured as a `nav` containing an ordered list, each `li` containing project, *i.e.*

[image: Screenshot of the <code>nav</code> with overlapping project <code>li</code>'s]

```html
<nav id='timeline'>
    <ol>
        <li class='project' id='zero'>
            <div class='description'>
                <h2> Project 0 </h2>
                <span> The project that changed everything </span>
                <div class='icon'></div>
            </div> <!-- div.description -->
        </li> <!-- li.project#zero -->
    </ol>
</nav> <!-- nav#timeline -->
```

I have a simple event loop to detect global mouse position and handle scroll detection,

```js
// 20ms event loop to update a global mouseX, mouseY position and handle scroll detection
var mouseX = null;
var mouseY = null;
var scrollTimeline = null;
var updateInterval = 10;
var scrolling = false;
window.onmousemove = function(event) {
    mouseX = event.clientX;
    mouseY = event.clientY;
    if (!scrollTimeline) {
        scrollTimeline = window.setInterval(scroll, updateInterval);
    }
};
```

Which in turn calls a simple scroll handler every 10ms,

```js
function scroll(event) {
    var buffer = window.innerWidth/4;

    var distanceToCenter = Math.abs(window.innerWidth/2-mouseX);
    var speed = distanceToCenter/(window.innerWidth/2);
    if (mouseX < buffer) {
        scrolling = true;
        scrollLeft(speed);
    }
    else if ((window.innerWidth - mouseX) < buffer) {
        scrolling = true;
        scrollRight(speed);
    }
    else {
        scrolling = false;
        window.clearInterval(scrollTimeline);
        scrollTimeline = null;
    }
}
```

All the actual scrolling is accomplished by adjusting the `left` attribute of the containing `nav` via two functions, `scrollRight` and `scrollLeft`, called with a `speed` argument depending on the mouse position.

```js
function scrollRight(speed) {
    var leftPixels = parseInt(getStyleProp(timeline, 'left'), 10);
    var toShift = Math.pow(speed,3)*updateInterval;
    var newLeft = leftPixels - toShift;

    if (newLeft >= -1400 && newLeft  <= 0) {
        timeline.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
    }
}
```

(`getStyleProp` is a simple utility function for getting the computed `left` attribute if it hasn't been explicitly set which I copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9883642/37772)):

```js
// Utility function to grab style properties when unset
function getStyleProp(elem, prop){
    if(window.getComputedStyle)
        return window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue(prop);
    else if(elem.currentStyle) return elem.currentStyle[prop]; //IE
}
```

#### What I've tried

So, with all of those basics out of the way, I've tried:

- Removing some of the CSS transitions that create the scalloped effect
- Using one image instead of six
- Adjusting `left` in a loop, one pixel at a time, instead of in small jumps
- Removing any of the contained text and their transitions.
- And removing any contained `li`'s in the `nav`--this solved the problem, but I'm not sure why/how that would be causing the [observed jitter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4gC9Vrj1fI)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the original jitter was because of the overhead of using the `saturate` transform in CSS.  I found a far better solution using [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/).